# Searching string value from two columns at once

Tags: c#, .net

I've got this method below where I am searching for a certain string value (`searchString`) inside all of the different fields. My problem is that I want the user to be able to search for a 'Name' and 'Surname' in a single search but the search query does not return any results. I've marked the line of code that I think is supposed to do the job in my code snippet below.

**Example:** There is a person in the database table called "Betty Suarez" and I want the user to be able to enter the name and surname into a textbox and then search for the name+surname and the results should return if the values was found. With my code below I can enter 'Betty' and it would return the person 'Betty Suarez' and the same with the 'Surname', but as soon as I type 'Betty Suarez', no value is returned.

```
var result = from info in joinInfo
             where info.user.Email.Contains(searchString)
             || info.user.Department.DepartmentName.Contains(searchString)
             || info.detail.Name.Contains(searchString)
             || info.detail.Surname.Contains(searchString)
             || info.detail.Name.Contains(searchString) && info.detail.Surname.Contains(searchString) //--- The problem line ---
             || info.role.RoleName.Contains(searchString)
             select new UsersView
             {
                 Id = info.user.Id,
                 Email = info.user.Email,
                 ...
             };
```

Comment: I think you are missing some parentheses, aren't you? It usually makes no sense to combine OR and AND operators on the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

```
var name = "Betty";
var surname = "Suarez";

Console.WriteLine(name.Contains("Betty Suarez"));
Console.WriteLine(surname.Contains("Betty Suarez"));
```

The basic idea is that as soon as user enters multi-word search criteria, you will have to employ additional logic of chopping up the input string and do something like:

```
... || info.detail.Name.ContainsAnyOf(searchStrings) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man :) I do not fully understand how `ContainsAnyOf` will help me at the moment, but I'm sure that I am not fully grasping what you are trying to explain to me. (to be fair, I should have been in bed by now), or could it be that I cannot find `ContainsAnyOf` because it is telling me that it does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you're searching for the entire string ("Betty Suarez") inside each of the sub-strings ("Betty" & "Suarez").

What you would need to do is something like split the input string into its components, for example:

```
var nameParts = searchString.Split(" ");
var result = from info in joinInfo
             where info.user.Email.Contains(searchString)
             || info.user.Department.DepartmentName.Contains(searchString)
             || info.detail.Name.Contains(nameParts[0])
             || info.detail.Surname.Contains(nameParts[1])
             || info.detail.Name.Contains(nameParts[0]) && info.detail.Surname.Contains(nameParts[1])
             || info.role.RoleName.Contains(searchString)
             select new UsersView
             {
                 Id = info.user.Id,
                 Email = info.user.Email,
                 ...
             };
```

Now keep in mind, I have given a very simple example, you will want to tweak it and play around with it, and include error handling to get it to work the way you need.

This is probably also an inefficient method of doing it, but it should set you on the right path to resolve the overall issue.

Comment: C# uses brackets to access array elements. ;-)

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly - Thank you for pointing that out, I use VB at work so my brain was stuck in that mode :)

Comment: @Taegost Thanks for the answer man! Yours I understand the most so far :) I've got one error though. When I use your advice/coding, I get the error `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. I can't find anything that can help me understand why it's doing this. I'm also not so clued up with arrays and sorry for only replying now

Comment: That's fine, I understand :)  That error was one of the things I was talking about with error handling, the way my example is written, it will *only* work if you enter both a first and last name, if you enter only one name, it'll throw that error because what it's doing is splitting the string into an array and using the space character (" ") to split it, so if there's only 1 name, there's no spaces, so it will create an array with only a single element, so the call to nameParts[1] will throw that error

Comment: Doing a multiple-criteria search of this nature is a bit outside of my current experience level so unfortunately I can't give you a good, concrete example of how to make it work in all scenarios, the best I can do is answer why it's happening and point you down the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the Input and search in the proper properties.

Also whatch out in your Where Clause I think you need brackets in your expected error line:

```
var result = from info in joinInfo
         where info.user.Email.Contains(searchString)
         || info.user.Department.DepartmentName.Contains(searchString)
         || info.detail.Name.Contains(searchString)
         || info.detail.Surname.Contains(searchString)
         || (info.detail.Name.Contains(searchString) && info.detail.Surname.Contains(searchString)) //--- The problem line ---
         || info.role.RoleName.Contains(searchString)
         select new UsersView
         {
             Id = info.user.Id,
             Email = info.user.Email,
             ...
         };
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't return any values for me, sorry man.

Comment: Have you split the input and checked whether it contains two words like the other ones explained ? thats the main problem in your code